string.c - memset: I am trying to understand, why is "int c" and not "char c" in the function prototype / signature?
Looking at the code from string.c for memset, why did the author choose "int c" and not "char c" ?
I was writing this function myself, and since it was "int c" I first attempted to cast the void *s to int* which gave me some questioning time.
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t count)
{
    char *xs = s;
    while (count--)
        *xs++ = c;
    return s;
}

